# Nest.js | @Exclude() decorator not working in the POST methods

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-transformer

Even with `@Exclude()` decorator from [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) library added to a variable, it's being returned when object is created.

Both with empty constructor and with the `toPlainOnly` property enabled it's fail:

```js
@Exclude()
password: string;
```

```js
@Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
password: string;
```

What to do?

Answer (score 12):

It's work for me:

Use `toPlainOnly` property enabled and too add `ClassSerializerInterceptor` like `GlobalInterceptor`:

```js
// your entity class

@Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
password: string;
```

```
// main.ts

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  .
  .
  .
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(
    new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector))
  );
}
```

Enable global serialization avoids the necessity to use `plainToClass` individually all time...

Comment: Thanks man! This solution worked perfectly for me after wasting my 3 days.