# Undefined type error. Make sure you are providing an explicit type for... After updating the packages

Tags: graphql, nestjs, nestjs-graphql

I've been using nestjs with graphql for quite some time and have encountered this error, luckily it's usually an easy fix. But after updating the project dependencies, this error began to appear on all fields of all models where the type was not specified in the Field decorator.

Error:

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/utils/reflection.utilts.js:17
            throw new undefined_type_error_1.UndefinedTypeError((0, lodash_1.get)(prototype, 'constructor.name'), propertyKey, index);
                  ^
Error: Undefined type error. Make sure you are providing an explicit type for the "value" of the "ServiceHistoryModel" class.
    at reflectTypeFromMetadata (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/utils/reflection.utilts.js:17:19)
    at applyMetadataFn (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/decorators/field.decorator.js:31:107)
    at singleCallFunctionWrapper (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/schema-builder/storages/lazy-metadata.storage.js:67:13)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/schema-builder/storages/lazy-metadata.storage.js:41:44
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at LazyMetadataStorageHost.load (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/schema-builder/storages/lazy-metadata.storage.js:41:26)
    at GraphQLSchemaFactory.create (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/schema-builder/graphql-schema.factory.js:35:53)
    at GraphQLSchemaBuilder.generateSchema (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql-schema.builder.js:35:52)
    at GraphQLSchemaBuilder.build (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql-schema.builder.js:22:31)
    at GraphQLFactory.generateSchema (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/graphql.factory.js:27:69)
```

ServiceHistoryModel:

```
@ObjectType()
export class ServiceHistoryModel {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  value: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  date?: Date;
}
```

This file did not change for about a month, and during this time the backend was deployed a bunch of times on local and production.

If I put () => String in the FIeld decorator, this error goes away. But this means that I will have to specify types for all fields, all models. Previously, everything worked fine if the field had a readable type, like string or Date. I reverted dependencies to previous versions, but that didn't help. I also tried deleting everything and installing it again. It looks like an internal dependency of one of the packages has broken. How can I fix this?

Edit: I found the previous version of package-lock.json, restored it and installed all the packages again via npm ci, this fixed the problem. But I still have no idea which package broke everything. When uploading to the server, the dependencies will be installed again, so simply using the old lock file is not a solution.

Comment: We are having the same issue with nestjs and graphq. We thought, it might have something to do with apollo. Though we wanted to migrate to mercurius, we removed all apollo dependencies but the error still occurs. 
The only thing I found, was this SO question about typescript decorators not working anymore, due to changes in version >= 4.2. But that also didn't help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941453/why-have-typescript-property-decorators-stopped-working-after-an-upgrade

If you find out anything, please give some update. I will do as well if I find out anything

Comment: @DerAlex Hi, the only thing that worked for me was rolling back previous versions - I just removed all ^ from package.json, making all versions absolute. And it still works, I think that the problem is in the nest packages. even @nestjs/typeorm updates caused this bug, most likely nestjs/core or similar peerDependency is the problem.

Comment: Hi. We also changed from npm to pnpm and updated all our dependencies to work with node 20.11. Yesterday I updated all dependencies again and now everything works (I still don't know why it's now working...) I am not sure if it is just a nestjs package specific problem or if it is a combination of nest, typescript and the tsconfig. If you want to, I can share my package.json and tsconfig. 
Also I found another question that looks promising: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545893/nest-js-exclude-decorator-not-working-in-the-post-methods